# Entity Framework objects do not contain a definition

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Ok so I am getting a problem in my controller when I try to build my solution. I have the controller, models and views all designed but my controller is failing to submit the data entered into my form to the actual local SQL Server database.

Below is a screenshot of my problem
Notice on both the [HttpPost] ActionResults the AddObject and ObjectStateManager are causing the problem.

[image]

Here is my connection string within the web.config file of my solution.

I cant seem to find a resource Online of understand why this is giving me this error!

Comment: Seems like your missing a reference. Could you try add System.Data.Entity?

Comment: Yes i have [using System.Data.Entity;] at the top of my controller.cs and have it under references in my solution

Comment: Check to see if you have an Add() method instead of AddObject(). Are you using dbcontext or objectcontext?

Comment: Add() removed the error... What about DeleteObject() or more to the point [db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(vendor, EntityState.Modified);]

Comment: On DbSet<T> you have a method called Remove() which marks the entity for deletion. It will get deleted when you call SaveChanges().

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using DbContext, since your collection is of type DbSet, and on this collection it is Add(TEntity) which are the appropriate method for adding items to the collection. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

On the other hand we have the ObjectContext, which uses ObjectSet. And on that collection AddObject() is the correct method for adding items. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To delete an entity, do something like this:

```
db.Vendors.Remove(vendor);
db.SaveChanges();
```

As a side note I would recommend you to use some sort of proxy models so that you dont expose your data model to the public.

Comment: db.Vendors.Remove(vendor); and db.Vendors.Add(vendor) both seem to remove the errors but neither are actually working? adding input wont actually submit that data to the database

Comment: Check your App_Data folder, do you have a mdf file there?

Comment: @eoinDeveloper - Can you post your connectionstring?